# JQM Calendar Show Multiple Months

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Am trying to use the [JQM Calendar](https://github.com/JWGmeligMeyling/jqm-calendar) to create an events calendar as detailed below. 
Qn: Is there a way I can output 3 months at ago instead of 1?

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '', function(){
  $("#calendar").jqmCalendar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.gajotres.net/sources/jQMCalendar/jw-jqm-cal.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.gajotres.net/sources/jQMCalendar/jw-jqm-cal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some silence here, is there an alternative calendar you may suggest to give me much flexibility in terms of adjusting months to show & marking days with events. Preferably PHP or JS please. Thanks

Comment: You need to instance 3 calendars, then the problem will be to get the first day of current month-1 & current month-2. For that, You will find a lot of code here on SO. BTW, IMHO the silence is because You are using an  outdated version of JQM (latest stable is 1.4.5)

Comment: Much appreciated @deblocker. Let me give that a try & perhaps use the latest version then comeback with a status which I guess will be hat you've pointed out - the first dates of month 2 & 3.

Comment: I actually found an easier option to a solution I wanted using the Availability Calendar [link](https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-availability-calendar-script/)  @deblocker so this' what I've built sofar [link](https://alphasoftlimited.com/themes/sosure/period-tips-advice/) - a few tweeks to go!